# Replace an old string with a new string in a main string using Scala 2.11

Tags: scala

I have the below 3 Strings -

```
old_string = "?doc lita:doi ?doi . "

new_string = "?d ?doi"

main_string = "SELECT  {     ?doc lita:doi ?doi . } WHERE  {     ?d a dm:Document .     ?d prism:doi ?doi .     }"
```

I'm trying to replace old string with new string in the main string with replaceAll(), but after running the below code, I dont see the replaceAll() working, as I get back the same main string again -

```
val final_str = main_string.replaceAll("old_string ","new_string ")
```

Comment: what is your expected output?
replaceAll replaces the given regex `select_str` in your case with `my_cols`

Comment: `main_string` doesn't contain `"select_str"` so the replace won't do anything... what do you actually think should happen?

Comment: Thanks for the responses ,
I forgot to replace the 2 variable names before posting. Now its better.
@JamesWhiteley I just want to replace the SELECT{} part  (?doc lita:doi ?doi . ) with ("?d ?doi")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val final_str = main_string.replaceAll("old_string ","new_string ")
```

will replace all occurrences of the literal string "`old_string`"    with "`new_string`".  It will not replace occurrences of the string in the variable `old_string` (unless, coincidentally, the value of `old_string` is "`old_string`").

You may want to try

```
val final_str = main_string.replaceAll(old_string, new_string)
```

(assuming that you want to replace occurrences of `?doc lita:doi ?doi .`  with `?d ?doi`)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, It does work.
Actually I had tried this too before posting, but didn't realize that my strings had some white spaces due to which my replaceAll didn't work. Now I'm good, after using trim() function.